# Which Mailing List Software?

Tags: email, mailing-list

[I'm moving](https://serverfault.com/questions/337678/should-i-run-my-own-mta/337800#337800) my mail infrastructure from mailup.com to an in house solution. I send roughly 65.000 emails a week and I'm aiming to double this within the next 6 months.

I gave a look at PhpList and GNU mailamn. What other options do I have?

I'm running CentOS and I can pick whatever MTA I prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at some of these resource for more research:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570943/whats-the-best-open-php-newsletter-manager

http://www.greepit.com/2010/03/best-open-source-email-marketing-software-roundup/

In the end, it depends on what kind of media you're mailing.

Answer (score 1):

If you wont something very stable, easy use, and oldest software around that is still useful then I can recommend [Citadel](http://www.citadel.org/).
It is fast, stable, easy to install, easy to use, and probably has more futures then you will ever need. The only thing is, it doesn't look pretty.