# SMTP server on debian 6.0 linux

Tags: linux, debian, smtp

I have some questions: I am using a SMTP service for sending monthly newsletter for my website (~3000 email addresses).
I was thinking: I already own a virtual server configured as a web server and secured, why not using it to send email and save 7€/month ??

Is this a reasonable idea or am I a fool?
Does anybody knows a good (and up-to-date) guide for debian squeeze linux? I have read the official documentation, but i've understood a little...

And again: what I'm talking about is the so-called "smtp-relay"?

Comment: How little is your time worth?  At 7 euros/month, it'll be a long time before the savings pay for the investment of your time to learn all this stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I run my own MTA?](http://serverfault.com/questions/337678/should-i-run-my-own-mta)

Comment: uhmm... considering the time for learn how to setup a smtp server, i guess 7€/month it's a reasonable price. This topic (mail server) is really huge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up a mailserver on Debian can be quite annoying. I hope you have a few days/weeks. I suggest starting with something easier.

If you want a decent guide about how to setup a mailserver, I learned it with this one: http://workaround.org/ispmail/squeeze

Which is a very comprehensive guide explaining everything step by step. I you want mailinglists you can set these up with either of these:

- mailman
- sympa (bad documented though)
- mlmmj

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your list of email addresses are all opted in and the recipients do want your emails (i.e. they don't think it is spam) then it makes perfect sense to send these yourself. Especially considering it's just 3000 addresses give or take. Any low power set up could handle that. The reason you want to be sure your recipients don't think it is spam is that you don't want to have your IP get a bad reputation and be listed everywhere.

I would advice to use mailman to manage the email list in addition to your Debian setup. Debian comes with exim4 by default, but you can switch to postfix if you prefer.

With regards to how to configure and set it all up I think you will have to ask separate more specific questions.

Comment: Yes, all addresses are opted in; thanks for the hint about mailman.
I need to study postfix/exim/mailman/etc... before asking anything.

So this wasn't a bad idea at all.

Comment: +1 and postfix is the way to go.

Comment: Well, "postfix vs. exim" is probably a holy war the same way "vi vs. emacs" is. :-) I like both, they share a few very important characteristics, stability, and licensed under gpl.